# What does this sentence mean in Stephen King's IT?

Tags: stephen-king

What does "He had put away nearly three sixpacks during the baseball game, and he was shagged." mean at the end of the paragraph?

> Tom was nearly asleep when the phone rang. He struggled halfway up, leaning toward it, and then felt one of Beverly’s breasts press against his shoulder as she reached over him to get it. He flopped back on his pillow, wondering dully who was calling on their unlisted home phone number at this hour of the night. He heard Beverly say hello, and then he drifted off again. He had put away nearly three sixpacks during the baseball game, and he was shagged.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular idiomatic usage, but from the context it obviously means "drunk/blotto/wasted/hammered/etc."

Comment: "put away" is a colloquialism for "consumed", "ate" or "drank", a "six pack" is six beverages (usually 12-ounce cans, and usually beer, though soft drinks are also said to come in six-packs) sold as a set, and "shagged" seems like maybe a New England-ism for "worn-out" and/or "drunk".  So, I'd read it as "He had [consumed] nearly [18 cans of beer] during the baseball game, and he was [drunk and tired]"

Comment: Bizarrely, King uses this word four times in his books and never with the same meaning twice - The one above (clearly meaning either "drunk" or "tired"), later in the same book to mean "caught" ("shagged foul balls"), in *Just after Sunset* to mean "hurried up" ("I shagged my elderly ass to the rear of the ambulance") and in *The Talisman* to mean "messy" ("greasy black hair shagged down his back to the shoulder").

Comment: Shagging balls, specifically in baseball, is relatively normal American slang. I suspect it comes from the etymology of "shag" meaning to shake or quiver. Shagging is a shimmying sort of dance. Shaggy hair bounces around. Shagging someone on your bed involves a lot of bouncing and shimmying. And someone trying to get under a fly ball is probably doing a decent amount of shimmying as they try to position torso and arm.

Comment: Which parts of the sentence are you wondering about? Your question seems to basically come down to "what do each of these words mean", which is the question dictionaries are intended to answer. A common definition of "sixpack", which you should find in just about every dictionary, is "a pack of six cans of beer". If you check the dictionary for "put away", you should find something like "consume food or drink". Similarly, you'll find a definition of "shagged" that is "extremely tired". Put those together and you should have your answer.

Comment: Where can you put away 3 six-packs of beer?  In the refrigerator, of course, but that wouldn't make you "wonder dully" or "drift off again".  In context, it can only mean putting them in your belly.  ***That*** would cause you to be drunk and sleepy (since it's after the game), when you would "wonder dully" or "drift off again".   Thus, contextually, "shagged" can only mean "drunk" (even though I've never heard that use of the word.

Answer (score 21):

As DavidW notes, "shagged" in this case simply means "drunk", likely drawing from the [British slang "shagged out"](https://www.britain-visitor.com/british-culture/british-slang#s), which means "tired". He's drunk almost eighteen (three times six) beers, which is a substantial amount of alcohol. Using this BAC calculator and making some guesses on bodyweight and an average 3 hour baseball game, [he'd have about a 0.34% BAC](https://www.calculator.net/bac-calculator.html?csex=m&bodyweight=200&bodyweightunit=pound&thour=3&tmin=0&ba=18&bsize=n330&babv=5&wa=&wsize=c150&wabv=12&la=&lsize=s50&labv=40&oa=&osize=250&osizeunit=ml&oabv=8&x=88&y=10), which is headed for a 0.4% level where fatality becomes a risk.

Comment: 18 cans of beer would indeed normally be a substantial amount of alcohol, except that this is American beer which is pretty much just frothy water

Comment: ^_^ All jokes aside, unless it's light beers, [the alcohol percentage of American beers is around 5%](https://homebrewacademy.com/beer-alcohol-content-list/), which is comparable to beers like Guinness. The taste, on the other hand...

Comment: This is definitely British and not US slang. I've checked A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional Uses, The American Dictionary of Slang and The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and they all say it's a British colloquialism.

Comment: Suddenly Felicity Shagwell is a much less libidinous name.

Comment: {nods} Although, as an individual character choice, you never know what people will have in their personal or intimate group slang. Some people are just trying to make fetch happen. And, for a societal microcosm, all it takes is one member of the group getting drunk and saying thinking is like swimming through shag carpet, and suddenly your friends group refers to being drunk as being "shagged", and you start using that word in your head.

Comment: "Shagged" in Ireland can mean tired, it has another, more . . . horizontal meaning too, but here it fits the "tired" interpretation.

Comment: Yeah shagged being tired / worn out is the more common usage in Australia / New Zealand as well. I've never heard it to mean drunk, we have other slang for that - p*ssed for example.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez, FWIW, even mainstream American beers can be "making love in a canoe", as it were.    See also [this list of beers by ABV range](https://www.findmeabrewery.com/beer-alcohol-content/#:~:text=Beer%20Brand).

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Shagged close to water?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yeah, but you also need to take into account that IT was written in 1986.  Back then I remember a distinct extra buzz when we "put away" a keg of Heineken as opposed to our regular staple of Bud.  American beer has come a long way since the 80s/90s.  Not least in quality, through the much wider presence of microbreweries.

Comment: It's an American novel and "drinking in the sun during a sports event", I am absolutely sure that the scene does not reference 5%-strong beer but rather a 4.2 light one. Putting the blood alcohol at a more surviveable 2.8 BAC

Comment: @Davislor, basically, ya!  But usually expressed in ruder terms.    I think it's Monty Python at the Hollywood Bowl where I first heard that analogy.